# locating element by css selector

Tags: python, css, selenium, css-selectors

I am trying to locate an element by css selector in chrome, I did:

1. right click on the object
2. inspect
3. right click the hightlight area in chrome developer tool
4. copy
5. copy selector.

my code is:

```
CreateANewDetector = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#home-page > 
div.banner-container > div.banner-btns > div")
```

however, the result is:

> Unable to locate element{"method":css selector","selector","selector"
>   div.banner-container > div.banner-btns > div")

what went wrong?

Comment: If you need additional help you may want to add the URL or HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) can help in your case try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://url.com'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('d:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
create_a_new_detector = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#home-page > div.banner-container > div.banner-btns > div")))
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks so much. I put the following lines in:

Comment: wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
 create_a_new_detectorwait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,\
                                           "#home-page > div.banner-container > div.banner-btns > div")))
create_a_new_detector.click()

Comment: But got raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: I change the wait time to 20, but it still have same issue

Comment: @PeterChao can you share the URL or HTML of the site?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#home-page .banner-container .banner-btns").find("div")
```

To find an element you have to use jquery selector and here we are traversing to the end div i.e, .banner-btns and tryong to find div inside it.May this explanation work

Comment: Done added explanation @JeffC